# React Router is showing error with switch

Tags: reactjs

I have this error message

Error: A  is only ever to be used as the child of  element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your  in a .

with this code

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import Services from "./Components/Services";
import Contact from "./Components/Contact";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/services">Blog Articles</Link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/contact">Contact Me</Link>
      </div>

      <hr />

        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/services">
          <Services />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/contact">
          <Contact />
        </Route>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please how do i resolve this

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your `<Route />` components with `<Switch />` component(as per [documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing)):

```js
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/services">
          <Services />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/contact">
          <Contact />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution: 01**

You can try using routes instead of Switch.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";

 <BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}>
      <Home/>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Solution: 02**

Did you try wrapping your Route tags in a switch? For example,

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route exact path="/register" component={SignUp}/>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
    <Route exact path="*" component={Error}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

**Solution: 03**

Switch is replaced in react-router-dom version 6. So that you need to install react-router-dom version 5. Now, your error should be solved.

```
npm install react-router-dom@5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for routing:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {

return (
    <div className="app">
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/post/create" exact>
                     <Form />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/:username" exact>
                    <Profile />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/accounts/edit" exact>
                    {user ? <EditProfile /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
                </Route>
                <Route path="/direct/:id" exact>
                    {user ? <Direct /> : <Login />}
                </Route>
                <NotFound404 />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
);
}

 export default App;
```